# How to keep factor strings after dplyr summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(v1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), v2 = c(3,3,4,4), v3 = c(11,21,31,41))
df

  v1 v2 v3
1  a  3 11
2  a  3 21
3  b  4 31
4  b  4 41
```

I want to summarise v3 on v2 and keep v1, with:

```
df %>% group_by(v2) %>% summarise(v1 = first(v1), s3 = sum(v3))
```

and get:

```
  v2 v1 s3
1  3  1 32
2  4  2 72
```

but I want:

```
  v1 v2 s3
1  a  3 32
2  b  4 72
```

Any idea how I cn keep the factor strings iso id's and the same order of the columns?

Comment: `select` works for ordering columns, `select(v1, v2, v3)` at the end.

Comment: If `v1` and `v2` are really exactly parallel like in your example, just group by both of them before summarizing - `group_by(v1, v2)`.

Comment: @rdw try updating `dplyr`.  When I run your code I get your desired answer.

Comment: I second @JacobH's comment..  Was able to get the expected output with `dplyr_0.4.3.9001` and `R 3.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and fast `data.table` solution.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# summarize
  output <- df[, .( v1=v1[1] , s3=sum(v3)), by=v2]

# reorder columns
  setcolorder(output, c("v1", "v2", "s3"))

#    v1 v2 s3
# 1:  a  3 32
# 2:  b  4 72
```

Answer (score 0):

You were so close.
Here the dplyr solution to your question.

```
df %>% group_by(v1,v2) %>% summarise(s3 = sum(v3))
```